# iText having issues with Anchors (clickable but nothing happens)

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to create a simple table of contents (the document is only 4 pages long).
The issue I have is that while my mouse does turn into a hand, when I click it nothing happens.
And yes the targets are on another page.

creation of a table of contents line:

```
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Contact information");
chunk.setLocalGoto("Contact information");  
document.add(new Paragraph(chunk));
```

One of the targets:

```
Anchor anchor = new Anchor("Contact information", font1);
anchor.setName("Contact information");
Chapter chapter = new Chapter(new Paragraph(anchor), 1);    
chapter.setNumberDepth(0);
document.add(chapter);
```

The `Goto String` matches with the `Anchor name` so I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What version of iText are you using?  This could be some neolithic bug that was fixed long ago...

Comment: 2.1.7/5.0.5 Just wanted to check if there was a lot of difference between the two for my requirements since the former uses LGPL while the latter uses AGPL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=46) from iText in Action, the internal link uses a `#` in the name.

Another approach would be to use `Chunk`s for both the link and the destination.

```
chunkDest.setLocalDesitination("foo");
...
chunkLink.setLocalGoto("foo"); // or "#foo"?
```

My reading of `PdfDocument` (localGoto and localDestination) leads me to believe that the order in which they're created doesn't matter... wait...  Nope, shouldn't matter so long as both are actually called.

Have you actually stepped through your code to be sure they're both Actually Called?

Another option:  End run.  Drop down to the PDF-native code and do it there.  Build your own `PdfDestination` for the chapter location and `PdfAction` for the TOC.  Something like this:

```
PdfDestination fitH = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FITH);
// the destination doesn't have a page associated with it until you call
//  gotoLocalPage.  Kinda goofy, but we can work with it.
PdfAction link = PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(pageNum, fitH, writer);
chunk.setAction(link);
```

NOTES:

1. You can reuse a given PdfAction if you need multiple links to the same spot.
2. There are many ways to define a PdfDestination, I just used the one I prefer.  YMMV.

Comment: Looks like you can't use Anchor's for the target, and Chunks to link to the target. Using 2 Chunks worked fine.

Comment: Using chunks for both ends is the solution. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example here: ftp://ns.tnet.dp.ua/pub/ORACLE/Developers/Java_Doc_LIB/PDFLib/iText/tutorial/ch03.html it looks like for internal links  you need to set the reference to be "#" + {anchor name}.

Example internal link:

```
Anchor anchor1 = new Anchor("This is an internal link");
anchor1.setName("link1");
Anchor anchor2 = new Anchor("Click here to jump to the internal link");
anchor.setReference("#link1");
```

Comment: That is if you use anchors for the links, I use chunks. I checked out that example but even then the links don't work that's why I tried chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Also if several years are passed since someone made this question, I will answer because yesterday I had more or less the same issue

This is my code:

```
//the destination anchor
Anchor target = new Anchor("a name", FONT_BOLD);
target.setName("link");
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(target);    

//the goto anchor
Anchor goto= new Anchor("go to the target "+i, FONT_BOLD);
goto.setReference("#link");
```

Also this piece of code doesn't work, the reason is that
you cannot create a new `Paragraph` passing an `Anchor` as parameter

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(target); //this will not work


Paragraph p = new Paragraph(); //this will work
p.add(target)
```